# Why doesn't `ReplaceAll` work in this situation?

Tags: replacement, scoping

I can work around this by using `With`, but it seems really odd to get the following:

```
PrimeQ[2]
PrimeQ[x] /. x -> 5
With[{x = 5}, PrimeQ[x]]
 *True*
 *False*
 *True*
```

Obviously there is a logical explanation. But what is it?

Comment: Because `PrimeQ[x]` is evaluated first, yielding `False`, so eventually you're doing `False /. x->5`.

Comment: `PrimeQ` has the rather undesireable property that it evaluates to `False` on symbolic input (which is bad because at this point, the question is actually undecidable.). `ReleaseHold[Hold[PrimeQ[x]] /. x -> 5]` works better.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks.

Comment: `Inactivate@PrimeQ[x] /. x -> 5 // Activate` also works.

Comment: Doing `PrimeQ[x] /. x -> 5 // Trace` helps to understand what happens. `Trace` is a good tool to remember.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I disagree that `PrimeQ`'s behaviour is undesirable: the general design of `Q` functions that they are meant to resolve to boolean values under all circumstances (with some annoying exceptions like `FileExistsQ`, which doesn't evaluate for non-strings). Programming in WL would be very tedious if the `Q` functions didn't follow this rule. You just need to keep that in mind when doing symbolic computations.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit You make a very good point. The `Q`-function are not seldomly used in argument patterns for functions (e.g. as `_?NumberQ`). This might also be the reason why it is `Positive` and not `PositiveQ`.